# Google map api shows grid

Tags: android, google-maps

I tried to integrate Google map API with android native application. But I got only grid only, I can't get the map. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Whenever you got gray grids, its confirmed that your key is not correct. Please register your project on Google Project console and use the correct key.

Comment: Issue is with your key 100%, register a proper key which is used for signing your app.

Comment: check http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/a-simple-example-using-google-maps.html may it help you.

Comment: This link may help you http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Comment: show your manifest, layout and other possible code files.

Answer (score 0):

Grids are shown because your key is not correct.Use the true key for your project which is registered in `Google Project Console`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting only grid instead of the map, usually it's Google Maps Authentication problem. To solve it I would suggest you to go over the following guide:

[Google Maps API V2 key](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

Follow all the steps of the guide and reproduce the key.
Next, follow this guide as well:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

to create application that integrates Google Maps API V2. Don't forget to remove the current installed application completely because Google Maps V2 caches the key you used before.